# WPF: How to synchronize async loaded listviews

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, asynchronous

I have a question about the syncronisation between loading resources async and keeping the selected element to the correct loaded resource. To be pricise I have a listview with users and one panel with his profile. If I choose that user, the user is loaded from an webservice and after that his data are shown in that profile-panel. Loading a user can be a very expensive operation (time) so I tried so make that loading async to prevent to block the whole UI-thread. I wrote in the ItemChange-Event something like this->

```
ItemChangeEvent(){
   Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
      .. load profile from Server
      this.Dispatcher.Invoke(.. some UI changes);
   });
}
```

Now it sometimes happens, that the user I selected in that listview, is not the user which is shown on the profile. My guess is, that any of the task is delayed and pushed his content after the "correct" user-profile task is finished. So how can I achieve that the loading is async but syncronisation with the current-selected-item?

Comment: Try to use synchronization with `lock` or other constructions

Comment: ReactiveUI has a very nice feature to handle this, see https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/blob/master/wpf/getting-started/ReactiveDemo/AppViewModel.cs#L80 to get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource) in the outer scope, and store the `CancellationToken` in a local variable inside the event handler. Ideally this token should be passed and used by the method that fetches the profile from the remote server, to avoid having ongoing tasks fetching data that are no longer needed.

Also instead of using the awkward `Dispatcher.Invoke` for switching back to the UI thread, you could take advantage of the modern and neat [async-await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) approach. The code after `await` continues automatically in the UI thread, without having to do anything special beyond adding the keyword `async` in the event handler:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _itemChangeTokenSource;

private async void ListView1_ItemChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _itemChangeTokenSource?.Cancel();
    _itemChangeTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = _itemChangeTokenSource.Token;
    var id = GetSelectedId(ListView1);
    Profile profile;
    try
    {
        profile = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return GetProfile(id, token); // Expensive operation
        }, token);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        return; // Nothing to do, this event was canceled
    }
    UpdatePanel(profile); 
}
```

It would be even more ideal if the expensive operation could become asynchronous. This way you would avoid blocking a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread every time the user clicked on the `ListView` control.

```
profile = await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    return await GetProfileAsync(id, token); // Expensive asynchronous operation
}, token);
```

---

**Update:** I made an attempt to encapsulate the cancellation-related logic inside a class, so that the same functionality can be achieved with fewer lines of code. It may be tempting to reduce this code in case it is repeated multiple times in the same window, or in multiple windows. The class is named `CancelableExecution`, and has a single method `Run` which accepts the cancelable operation in the form of a `Func<CancellationToken, T>` parameter.
Here is a usage example of this class:

```
private CancelableExecution _updatePanelCancelableExecution = new CancelableExecution();

private async void ListView1_ItemChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var id = GetSelectedId(ListView1);
    if (await _updatePanelCancelableExecution.Run(cancellationToken =>
    {
        return GetProfile(id, cancellationToken); // Expensive operation
    }, out var profile))
    {
        UpdatePanel(await profile);
    }
}
```

The `Run` method returns a `Task<bool>`, that has the value `true` if the operation was completed successfully (not canceled). The result of a successful operation is available via an `out Task<T>` parameter. This API makes for less code, but also for less readable code, so use this class with caution!

```
public class CancelableExecution
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _activeTokenSource;

    public Task<bool> RunAsync<T>(Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> function,
        out Task<T> result)
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = tokenSource.Token;
        var resultTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>(
            TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        result = resultTcs.Task;
        return ((Func<Task<bool>>)(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var oldTokenSource = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _activeTokenSource,
                    tokenSource);
                if (oldTokenSource != null)
                {
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        oldTokenSource.Cancel(); // Potentially expensive
                    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
                var task = function(token);
                var result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                resultTcs.SetResult(result);
                return true;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex) when (ex.CancellationToken == token)
            {
                resultTcs.SetCanceled();
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                resultTcs.SetException(ex);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(
                    ref _activeTokenSource, null, tokenSource) == tokenSource)
                {
                    tokenSource.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }))();
    }
    public Task<bool> RunAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> function, out Task<T> result)
    {
        return RunAsync(ct => function(), out result);
    }
    public Task<bool> Run<T>(Func<CancellationToken, T> function, out Task<T> result)
    {
        return RunAsync(ct => Task.Run(() => function(ct), ct), out result);
    }
    public Task<bool> Run<T>(Func<T> function, out Task<T> result)
    {
        return RunAsync(ct => Task.Run(() => function(), ct), out result);
    }
}
```

Comment: @EnemyArea I updated my answer, adding a componentized implementation of the same idea.

Comment: @EnemyArea a possible problem of this solution (the async-await solution in general) is that you may get an `ObjectDisposedException` when closing the window, while an async operation is still running in the background. I am sure this is a problem for Windows Forms, but I am not sure about WPF. In case you have this problem, you could set a flag on the `Window.Closed` event, and then check this flag on every continuation (after every `await` add a line `if (_closed) return;`).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use `CancellationToken` to cancel previous load task once other user is selected. This can be achieved in few steps:

1. Create instance field `CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource`
2. change your handler:

```
ItemChangeEvent(){
   // first, try to cancel previous event
   _tokenSource?.Cancel();
   // then, update token source; previous object will be collected eventually
   _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   // finally, add cancellation token from token source to task creation
   Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
      .. load profile from Server
      this.Dispatcher.Invoke(.. some UI changes);
   }, _tokenSource.Token);
}
```

Comment: I added the method "ThrowIfCancellationRequested" to your code, but it still not work :/

Comment: @EnemyArea The basic idea is the right one, but there is much more to do to get it done right. ReactiveUI has done this already for you and you only need to use it