# How to manage many CPU-intensive operations without slowing down the UI?

Tags: c#, user-interface, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, task-parallel-library

My Xamarin.Forms app contains a Slider that, when changed, causes an image to be processed based on the Slider value. The image processing is a CPU-intensive operation that takes about 200 ms to complete. As a result, the responsiveness of the Slider is very poor.

I moved the image processing to a separate thread, but the response is still slow. However, when I replace the operation with `Thread.Sleep(200)` the response is great. This leads me to believe that even when run on a separate thread, the image processing is taking up all CPU resources since the Slider value can change much more frequently.

Here's my current solution: when the Slider is changed, add an image processing `Action` to a list (but don't execute it yet). Every 1000 ms, take the last `Action` in the list and clear the list. Execute the `Action` asynchronously. This would prevent too many image processing tasks from taking up all the CPU time. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Timer timer;
    private List<Action> actions;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        timer = new Timer(200);
        timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;

        actions = new List<Action>();
    }

    // Processed image to be displayed
    private SKBitmap image;
    public SKBitmap Image
    {
        get => image;
        set => Set(ref image, value);
    }

    // Slider value to be used in image processing
    private double threshold;
    public double Threshold
    {
        get => threshold;
        set => Set(ref threshold, value);
    }

    // Command is called whenever the Slider value is changed
    public ICommand SetThresholdCommand =>
        new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            actions.Add(() => ProcessImageAsync(Threshold));
        });

    private async void ProcessImageAsync(double threshold)
    {
        SKBitmap processedImage = null;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            processedImage = VisionService.ProcessImage(threshold);
        }

        Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            Image = processedImage;
        }
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (actions.Any())
        {
            actions.Last()();  // execute the last action added
            actions.Clear();   // ignore all previous actions
        }
    }
}
```

This solution works, but having a timer feels hacky, and I don't like the arbitrary value of 1000 ms, which is not optimal and will most likely need to be different on other devices. What are some better solutions?

Comment: What does ProcessImageAsync look like? What technique were you using to run it on another thread?

Comment: Google for xamarin forms event debounce. Take a read of https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69118/how-to-delay-uisearchbar-textchanged-event for example

Comment: @mason I've added more code to show how the ProcessImageAsync works. It uses `Task.Run` to execute the real image processing operation, then it updates the Image property on the UI thread.

Comment: https://reactiveui.net/ has such a debounce as an example on their main page

Comment: There's is no need for `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` because you are _already_ on the UI thread

Comment: @MickyD That's what I thought, too, but I was getting an exception there, and when I checked the thread ID, it wasn't on the UI thread. I even tried ConfigureAwait(true) and it still wasn't on the UI thread.

Comment: Hmm that is interesting.  Apart from the UI is there anything else that could invoke the `SetThresholdCommand` that is possibly already set the context to non-UI?

Comment: If you could make the image processing to be cancelable (for example by observing a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) every time a line of pixels has completed), then take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120120/wpf-how-to-synchronize-async-loaded-listviews) question which features a similar problem.